# Spring security next steps

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security configured through java. It's a pretty simple configuration. The world should be able to GET without credentials. I want only admin users from a particular subnet to POST.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/status", "/configure")
//                .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .access("hasIpAddress('192.168.4.0/24')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .denyAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
            ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("dashboard.xxxx.yyy.zzz").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

hasIpAddress() works. hasRole() does not. When it does, I will "and" them.
I have spent three days trying every single page I could Google and not a single one of them got me there.

I am testing using `curl -u dashboard.xxx.yyy.zzz:password https://xxx.yyy.zzz:8443/status -d ''`

NOTE: I plan to eventually get the username from an x509 cert, but I wanted to start simple.

Comment: I will get a 403 Forbidden error. The POST will not occur. Nothing in the logs.

Comment: You are not logged in. Without authentication you are anonymous.

Comment: I thought the curl -u paramater handled that. But it would certainly explain things.

Comment: You didnt configure any authentication type. I guess you will use basic auth, then you have to add `httpBasic()` to your configuration.

Comment: Thank you. All those pages and not a single one mentioned httpBasic. That, combined with changing the password to {noop}password has gotten me past this hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add:

```
http.httpBasic();
```

I think that you should write a simple  `.hasRole("ADMIN")`.
Indeed, when using the `authorities()` method it is needed to include the `ROLE_` prefix.
When using the `roles()` method, do not include the `ROLE_` prefix.

In addition to your code you also need a password encoder (but maybe you have it already) something like:

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Finally have you noticed that your user in memory is  `dashboard.xxxx.yyy.zzz` and the one in the command line is `dashboard.xxx.yyy.zzz`? (an `X` is missing).

Comment: That extra x was a typo, I'm guessing the {noop} prefix in front of password tells Spring to use that password encoder. The big winner was httpBasic. How could so many pages of Spring Configuration websites fail to mention this? It just seems so fundamental. I was beating my head against the wall for 3 days,